# Shiny effect (Flutter)

Tags: animation, flutter

I need to apply a shiny effect on a logo on the splash screen. The aim is to reproduce the effect of the splash screen of Glassdoor app. Any idea about how to code this, please?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using [shimmer](https://pub.dev/packages/shimmer). Their example is pretty easy and should get you quite far.

Answer (score 2):

There is another **newer** Flutter package [ [shimmer_animation](https://pub.dev/packages/shimmer_animation) ] that might just be exactly what you are looking for. This newer **shimmer_animation** package does not override the image you want to show with a base color like the other [ [shimmer](https://pub.dev/packages/shimmer) ] package, recommended by @Hannes-Kuttner.

Answer (score 1):

@Hannes Thank you for your reply! I tried the shimmer effect.

Here my code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(185, 40, 47, 1),
      body: new Center(
      child:SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
        //height: 100.0,
        child: Shimmer.fromColors(
          baseColor: Colors.transparent,
          highlightColor: Colors.white,//.withOpacity(0.2),
          child: Image.asset('assets/NishkamSWATLogoOfficialSplash.jpg',
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,)
        ),
      ),

    ),
   );
  }
```

But the image doesn't show [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OZyj.png)